# Sound cannot be unmuted

Tags: sound, xubuntu, kubuntu

[image]

I hit mute a couple of times. The mixer shows its unmuted, the menu for the tray icon shows its unmuted, but the on-screen display thinks its muted and no sound plays.

I restarted. The tray icon shows muted. I unmuted it, but there is no sound.

I then went to KDE and unmuted. This is a successful workaround.

Is there a way I can mute and unmute with XFCE?

My system is XFCE with Kubuntu 15.04, maybe an unusual combination. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try
`alsactl init` 
which initialize all sound devices to a default state.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! But I don't know why the sound was muted in the first plave.